# How to see all databases a processes currently accesses

Tags: sql-server

I wonder if there's a way to see all databases a running process accesses? I know about `sys.dm_exec_requests` and `sys.sysprocesses`, but they only display the "original" database.

For example you run something like this:

```sql
select * from table1 t1
inner join anotherdatabase.dbo.table2 t2
  ON t2.id = t1.id
```

I want to be able to run some code and get both current and anotherdatabase while the above query is running. This is needed for some admin restore tasks.

The only way I can think of is to try and parse the query plan, but maybe there's something better?

Comment: There is no DMV that tracks this afaik; you might look at extended events possibly.

Comment: What about this kind of query? - `USE DatabaseA; SELECT * FROM DatabaseB.dbo.Table1 INNER JOIN DatabaseC.dbo.Table2 ON Table1.Key = Table2.Key`. There's 3 databases involved, `DatabaseA`, `DatabaseB`, `DatabaseC`, but no objects are actually accessed from `DatabaseA`. It's just the context of execution. Would you want to know about all 3 databases or just the 2 with objects being accessed from?

Comment: Ideally i only want to know which databases will get my connection killed if running "alter database X set single_mode with rollback immediate" :) But it's fine if i get all 3 databases too. I'd rather shoot too much than too few in this case

Comment: That would depend on what locks are being held, you probably want to look at `dm_tran_locks` and filter on `request_session_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say in comments that you just want info for all transactions that would be affected by `set single_mode with rollback immediate`. For that you probably want to look at `sys.dm_tran_locks`

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;  -- use read uncommitted for sys queries

select
  r.*
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
where r.session_id in (
    select
      t.request_session_id
    from sys.dm_tran_locks t
    join sys.databases d on d.database_id = t.resource_database_id
);

set transaction isolation level read committed;
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising, i'll give it a spin tomorrow. I'm guessing resource_database_id is the one i should be looking at to get all databases being "read"

Comment: You can filter `sys.databases` in the inner query using `name` etc